# mxe cross compiling for windows ... where are stdout messages?

Tags: g++, cross-compiling, wine, mxe

I'm cross compiling a basic C++ Windows XP console application from my Debian host system using [MXE](http://mxe.cc) (i686-pc-mingw32-g++). When running it on my Debian system (thanks to Wine), I can see the stdout output on the console. But if I run the same executable on Windows XP, from Windows console, I don't see my stdout output ... (using `printf` function).

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what the issue was?

Comment: No, I still dont know

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?